# How to sync 2 async fetches in Parse?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

So I have a PFobject A that contains 2 other PFobjects B C as value. When I construct my local object a, I would need both of the objects B C. So first I fetch a by doing a query:

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "A")
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("1", block: { (a, error) -> Void in
```

Then I get b and c from a

```
var b = a!["B"] as! PFObject
var c = a!["C"] as! PFObject
```

Then I will need to fetch b and c objects individually

```
b.fetchInBackgroundWithBlock({ (fetchedB, error) -> Void in
```

The problem is, the fetching methods is async and if I put them in the same thread I won't be guaranteed to have both of them fetched in the end.

One solution is to have the fetching nested in call-backs so that once one fetch is done it will start the other.

```
b.fetchInBackgroundWithBlock({ (fetchedB, error) -> Void in
    c.fetchInBackgroundWithBlock({ (fetchedC, error) -> Void in
        println(fetchedB)
        println(fetchedC) // Now they have values
        var myA = A(validB: fetchedB, validC: fetchedC) // Construction can continue
```

But if more objects are needed, it will become nesting in nesting. Like:

```
b.fetchInBackgroundWithBlock({ (fetchedB, error) -> Void in
    c.fetchInBackgroundWithBlock({ (fetchedC, error) -> Void in
        d.fetchInBackgroundWithBlock({ (fetchedD, error) -> Void in
            e.fetchInBackgroundWithBlock({ (fetchedE, error) -> Void in
```

However b,c,d and e are not dependent on each other - it should be perfect to fetch them on separate threads!

So is there a way to make the call-backs wait for each other at some point in the main thread to make sure all objects are fetched?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `includeKey()` method on the first `PFQuery` to tell parse to fetch both class B and C when performing the query. [Relevant documentation for `includeKey`](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries-relational/iOS)